# jwt prevents me from seeing other users' profiles nodejs, angular

Tags: node.js, angular, authentication, jwt

I followed a tutorial on how to create an authentication system. I tried to understand as much as possible while following the tutorial, but there are things that I still don't get, and now I've come to a problem that I've tried many things to fix but the answer is still negative. The problem is that the jwt middleware only allows me to see the profile of the user that I am logged in as, but I don't want that, I want a user to be able to see every other users' profiles, how can I do that? Thanks in advance!!
For the backend, here is my "user.route.js"

```
router.get("/profile/:id",auth, async (req, res) => {

    try {
      // request.user is getting fetched from Middleware after token authentication
      const user = await User.findById(req.user.id);
      res.json(user);
    } catch (e) {
      res.send({ message: "Error in Fetching user" });
    }
  });
```

for front end, here is my "authentication.service.ts"

```
export interface UserDetails{
  username: string
  email: string
  password: string
  firstName: string
  lastName: string
  exp: number
  iat: number
}
interface TokenResponse{
  token: string
}
export interface TokenPayload{
  username: string
  email: string
  password: string
  firstName: string
  lastName: string
}
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthenticationService {
  private token: string

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) {}

  private saveToken(token: string): void{
    localStorage.setItem('usertoken', token)
    this.token = token
  }
  private getToken(): string{
    if(!this.token){
      this.token = localStorage.getItem('usertoken')
    }
    return this.token
  }
  public getUserDetails(): UserDetails{
    const token = this.getToken()
    let payload
    if(token){
      payload = token.split('.')[1]
      payload = window.atob(payload)
      return JSON.parse(payload)
    }else{
      return null
    }
  }
  public isLoggedIn(): boolean{
    const user = this.getUserDetails()
    if(user){
      return user.exp > Date.now()/ 1000
    }
    else{
      return false
    }
  }
  public login(user: TokenPayload): Observable<any>{
    const base = this.http.post('/user/login', user)
    const request = base.pipe(
      map((data: TokenResponse) => {
        if(data.token){
          this.saveToken(data.token)
        }return data
      })
    )
    return request
  }
  public register(user: TokenPayload) : Observable<any>{
    const base = this.http.post('/user/register', user)
    const request = base.pipe(
      map((data: TokenResponse) => {
        if(data.token){
          this.saveToken(data.token)
        }
        return data
      })
    )
    return request
  }
  public profile(id): Observable<any>{
    const username = this.getUserDetails().username
    return this.http.get(`/user/profile/${id}`,
    {
      headers: {Authorization: `${this.getToken()}`}
    })
  }
  public logout(): void{
    this.token = ''
    window.localStorage.removeItem('usertoken')
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/')
  }

}
```

and this is the "profile.component.ts" code

```
 ngOnInit() {
    
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      const id = params.id;
      this.auth.profile(id).subscribe(
        user => {
          this.details = user
        },
        err => {
          console.error(err)
        }
      )
  })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

req.user up there is filled in by the authorization middleware, it does not use the id from url path like you want. For that you should use req.params.id

Comment: Thank you so much, it's now working, but when I'm not logged in and try go to a user's profile, I get this error: "Cannot read property 'username' of null". do you know why?